# Need to modify the Progress Bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, loading

Hello i want some modification in this script, i want to put a timer in this  or you can say i want this script in this way

Here's the original Code -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#sample_goal').goalProgress({
            goalAmount: 600,
            currentAmount: 200,
            textBefore: '$',
            textAfter: ' raised.'

        });
    });
</script>
```

I want to add two functions in this

It increments the no. after regular interval of time like
currentAmount: 200,
incrementAmount: 20,
incrmentTimer:2 hour,

So it will be like 200, 220(After two hours), 240(Next two hours) etc...

http://boogallery.com/soft/

Please HELP

Comment: I am not sure what you really want, but think that javascript/jquery etc are front-end langauges. Are you sure that somebody will keep your page opened for 2 hours? Your problem should have solution in back-end ( i guess ). Also post some code you've tried

Comment: Well i don't want to use any kind of database, i just want to embed a simple timer in backend, which automatically increases a static number Daily after a regular interval of time,

Comment: Or it would be better if anyone find me similar kind of script

Comment: As an hint : you have to calculate the ammount increasing with php ( make some basic math with your time interval ) and then return that value inside a function with an ajax request (jquery). Pass the function to `currentAmount`. Just get some more extra docs

Comment: Aah, its very hard for me to do this thing which you mentioned, even i'm not good in JS/PHP.. My bad luck

Comment: people arn't going to write the code for you. Your logic is fundamentally flawed though. As the first user pointed out, somebody will have to keep the page open for two hours. If you close the browser, it will reset. Unless this is some public thing that sits on a screen and people can see?

Comment: But I don't want to do like this, i want to set a counter just like on "Coming Soon" Pages type of scripts, Like Starting Time- 30 Nov 2014, 11 AM ,so it uses this time and automatically increases the value without any other requirement, everything should be static, and the output will be same for all users, suppose, if i open the site after 2 hours, i.e 1 PM, the value should be incremented...THIS IS MY LOGIC

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

http://jsfiddle.net/fs9gc3p5/4/

**CSS:**

```
#progressBar {
    width: 600px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #eee;
}
#progressBar div {
    height: 100%;
    line-height:50px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 28px;
    width: 0;
    background-color: #ff008c;
    padding:0 0 0 10px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-family:'helvetica neue', helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="progressBar"><div></div></div>
```

**JQ:**

```
var goalAmount = 600;
var startAmount = 200;
var incrementAmount = 20;

var startDate = new Date('2014-11-29T01:00:00');

function progress(percent, $element) {

    $element = $('#progressBar');

    //calculate the difference in hours.
    var currDate = new Date();
    var h = Math.abs(currDate - startDate) / 36e5;
    h = parseInt(h);

    //calculated interval: every two hours increases the amount of 20    
    var interval = h;
    if (interval % 2) h--;
    interval = parseInt(interval / 2);

    var newAmount = startAmount + incrementAmount * interval;

    // h  | interval | newAmount
    // ---------------------------
    // 0  |    0     |    0
    // ---------------------------
    // 1  |    0     |    0
    // ---------------------------
    // 2  |    1     |   220
    // ---------------------------
    // 3  |    1     |   220
    // ---------------------------
    // 4  |    2     |   240
    // ---------------------------
    // 5  |    2     |   240
    // ---------------------------
    // 6  |    3     |   260
    // ---------------------------
    // 7  |    3     |   260
    // ---------------------------
    // 8  |    4     |   280
    // ---------------------------
    // 9  |    4     |   280
    // ---------------------------
    // 10 |    5     |   300
    // ---------------------------
    // 11 |    5     |   300


    //calculate procent of progress bar
    var percent = newAmount * 100 / goalAmount;

    //draw
    var progressBarWidth = percent * $element.width() / 100;
    $element.find('div').animate({
        width: progressBarWidth
    }, 500).html('$' + newAmount + " raised.");
}

progress();
```

Comment: Thank you so much, But from Where can i set the Time interval , like i want to update the increment by no. 20 after every 2 hours or like

Comment: I'm sorry I missed that part. I added changes.